# computer I/0- Computer systems and architecture

Tags: architecture, system

Problem 2

Consider a computer system that is operated by an IT staff through a keyboard. From
statistics, it is known that the IT staff, in average, enters 90 keyboard commands per
3-hour duration.

a. Suppose that the CPU uses a programmed I/O technique that scans the keyboard
every 50 ms. Evaluate the number of scan operations that the CPU performs within a
3-hour duration.

b. If the computer uses interrupt-driven I/O instead of programmed I/O, analyse by what
fraction the number of keyboard visits by the CPU can be reduced.

**Problem 2 Answer**
From the question, IT staff enters 90 keyboard commands per 3-hour duration.

a) Programmed I/O technique that scans keyboard every 50 ms.
No of scan operations within 3-hour duration: `3 hours/50 ms = 3 x 3600 x 1000/50 = 216000`

The question is where the 1000 divided by 50 ms. Where does the number 1000 come from in the question? Is there a certain way to work this number out?

Answer (score 0):

Because `3 * 3600 * 1000` is the amount of `ms` three hours have.

Comment: this is not helpful at all state the obvious.

Comment: That is what you asked. "Where does the number 1000 come from in the question?"

Comment: yes but if I read the question without the answer how do I work out the number 1000 I know how to work everything out except the number 1000. what does the number 1000 represent? 1000ms in 1 hour?

Comment: oh right thankyou for your answer I appreciate it you have saved me valuable time.